# MySqlConnection object doesn't have state property?

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-2.0, database-connection

I'm querying from C# application. I can do this:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conString);
conn.Open();
//do database operation
```

Now how do I get the connection state of the `conn` object? What is strange is I get the intellisense dropdown showing the `State` property for `MySqlConnection` object and automatically leads me to `ConnectionState` enum from which I can choose. I could write the below code:

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    //print "Open"
```

But when I closely examined, I understood the `ConnectionState` enum is of type `System.Data`!! How do I get that automatically when I'm equating it with `MySqlConnection` object??

Also how do I get the connection state of MySQL connection like this:

```
if (conn.State == //equal to what?
```

Comment: ? What's the problem with the `ConnectionState` being in namespace System.Data.Common? MySqlConnection is derived from DBConnection which exposes `ConnectionState `

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. My application being too large I didn't compile it yet. Let me see..

Comment: then I don't think there's a problem

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin Thanks Oscar for your help. Lemme compile it and see.

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin , if you can post it as answer not only that I can mark it as answer, but it may help someone in future to quickly understand as well. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MySqlConnection` is derived from `DBConnection` which is an abstract class that defines how all database connections should behave (that derive from `DBConnection`). Thus will all these connections expose `ConnectionState` which is in the `System.Data.Common` namespace. So this is valid:

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
```